# angular material animation performance , md-icon issue on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, angular-material

I am building Android application using Angularjs, Angular material and Cordova. 
Can somebody help on below issues. Can someone suggest tips/tricks to improve/fix below points?

Issue ~1:
Animations are very very slow on android device. Mainly ripple effects/animations given to md-button are slow. See below Html . 
Code:

```
<div>
    <md-content>
        <md-list>
            <md-item ng-repeat="item in tags">
                <md-item-content>

                    <md-button class="md-grid-item-content tile"
                               aria-label="{{item.name}}"
                               ui-sref="crop({cropId: item.id})">
                        <div class="md-tile-center">
                            <img ng-src="{{item.imageSource}}" class="face" alt="{{item.name}}" height="64" width="64">
                        </div>
                    </md-button>                   
                    <div class="md-tile-content">
                        <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
                        <h4>{{item.text}}</h4>
                    </div>
                </md-item-content>
            </md-item>
        </md-list>
    </md-content>
</div>
```

Issue ~2:
Multiple click on md-button makes application not responding. Does not give intuition of which button is active or focus.

Issue ~3:
I observed that with Crome browser on Laptop, there are few problems for demo site also (https://material.angularjs.org), md-button icons are not visible. However same works in firefox. May be md-icon has changed in new build?

See : [Git issue 1177](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1177)

Comment: Issue #3: Have you tried using font awesome "fa fa-" icons? You can just use it like `<md-icon class="fa fa-fw fa-times"></md-icon>` (after loading the font-awesome files from cdn)